# How to check authentication and automatically redirect to login state with ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

so I have this function in my `run` in angularjs (running AngularJS v1.2.26)

```
.run(function(....) {
    authService.authCheck();

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if (next.requireLogin) {
            if (!authService.isLoggedIn()) {
                $location.path('/login');
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });

})...
```

when directly accessing a URL that requires authentication e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8080/secret`, the function always redirects to the login path, clearly after debugging it for a while it evaluates to false all the time. when accessing default page then going to the specified route it runs without any problems.

This is part of my `authService`

```
this.authCheck = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: '/api/login'
    }).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if (status === 200) {
            userIsAuthenticated = true;
        } else {
            userIsAuthenticated = false;
        }
        $rootScope.loginStatus = userIsAuthenticated;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        userIsAuthenticated = false;
        $rootScope.loginStatus = userIsAuthenticated;
    });
};

this.isLoggedIn = function() {
    return userIsAuthenticated;
};
```

So every time I have a break point on `!authService.isLoggedIn()` I see that it evaluates to false even though the function in the run block tries to authenticate it before reaching the `$rootScope.$on` function.

What exactly is preventing the state of `userIsAuthenticated` variable from being persistent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.authCheck` in your `authService` is asynchronous, which means that `userIsAuthenticated` won't be set to true until it actually finishes for the first time. If you followed the route you're on now, you'd have to write some more complex code for waiting if the check isn't completed yet and then redirecting. However, that's a messy sub-optimal option.

The best way to go here is to let `ui-router` work this out for you. Create a common ancestor state for all your states that require login, e.g. `'session'`. Then make that state's resolution wait for your authentication check using `resolve` option. If not authenticated, create a specific state transfer rejection error, which you can elsewhere catch and act upon (redirect to login).

```
.state('session', {
    resolve: {
        authentication: ['authService', '$q', function (authService, $q) {
            return authService.checkAuthentication().then(function () {
                if (!authService.isAuthenticated) {
                    return $q.reject({
                        notAuthenticated: true
                    });
                }
            });
        }]
    },
    // ...
})
.state('secret', {
    parent: 'session',
    // ...
});
```

and then

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function (_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, error) {
    if (error.notAuthenticated) {
        $state.go('login');
    }
});
```

(you'll need to properly return from your authentication check as well)

```
checkAuthentication: function () {
    return $http({...})
        .success(...)
        .error(...);
}
```

Comment: so even though I'm not using promises, that call (the `$http`) is still considered async call? Thanks for the snippet I'll give it a try when I'm home.

Comment: `$http` call is always asynchronous to prevent locking up the browser. And you _are_ using promises - return value is a promise extended with special functions `success` and `error` :) For my sample to work, you'll just need to return the whole thing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you allow the application to send request from /secret ?
It may prevent you to send any request from there so it redirects you to login

Comment: `/secret` checks for an auth token (session) with the right privileges that's all it is doing. The issues is that I can access `/secret` and post a valid form from there and the server is ok with it but the initial request is causing the issue like I said.

Comment: I understand that the problem is the app changes the root before the authentication is done! You can get around this problem via using a service to triger the code in the event $routeChangeStart 
without using it (this is the fastest solution if you have to complete this functionality asap)